# Was Barack Obama nicknamed Barack Oganja?

Tags: barack-obama, marijuana

A Twitter account named *History in Pictures* (followed by 515,501 users) [tweeted the following](https://twitter.com/HistoryInPics/status/405221862872870912):

> President Obama was known to be heavy marijuana smoker in his teen & college days. His nickname was "Barack Oganja".

The following image accompanied the text.

[image]

As I write this, the tweet has been retweeted 4,174 times and favourited 2,448 times. This claim has also been made on [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/fact5/posts/366700466713262) (332,000 likes) and other [random sites](http://inagist.com/all/264579603518070785/).

1. Is that Barack Obama in the photograph?
2. Has he been known to smoke pot? Heavily?
3. Was he ever nicknamed Barack Oganja?

If this is completely fabricated, please (try to) point out the source of this rumour.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. [Yes, this is Barack Obama](http://content.time.com/time/photogallery/0,29307,1866765_1815174,00.html). It is a photo by Lisa Jack, taken in 1980 at Occidental College. (From Lisa Jack's [artist statement](http://www.mbart.com/artists/_Lisa%20Jack/_artist-statement/).) The work was [exhibited at M+B Gallery in West Hollywood](http://www.mbart.com/artists/_Lisa%20Jack/_other%20works/_3244,14/), among other places.
2. He has been known to smoke pot: ["*I inhaled, frequently. That was the point.*"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpBzQI_7ez8&t=57)
3. I can find no evidence in any text online that the claim is true. (This does not prove that it is false, though.)

   The first online reference that I could find to "Barack Oganja" as an early nickname for Barack Obama is on May 18, 2012:

   - https://www.facebook.com/fact5/posts/366700466713262
   - https://twitter.com/FactBoook/status/203585034484068352

   This is consistent with [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends/explore?q=barack%20oganja#q=barack%20oganja&cmpt=q) not showing any activity for this term before June 2012.

   [image]

   One individual created this nickname for themself prior to 2012.

   - https://soundcloud.com/madfatdubsbro

   One user attributed a Barack Obama quote to "Barack Oganja" on December 4, 2011, but didn't claim it was a nickname from his younger years.

   - http://freak.no/forum/showpost.php?s=6445eb8566606c81c72b80e19cd1b731&p=2364430&postcount=20

   Two marijuana growers named a strain of marijuana "Barack Oganja" (reported December 4, 2009)

   - http://thephoenix.com/Boston/Life/93793-weed-grows-in-Boston/?page=4#TOPCONTENT

   One blog called Barack Obama "Barack O-Ganja" in a headline on October 26, 2009, but didn't connect it to a nickname from Obama's earlier years.

   - http://theburbslife.com/2009/10/states-dealing-with-new-ganja-law/

Comment: "The Sun" is not your most reliable source. Do you have another?

Comment: @DJClayworth [Time](http://content.time.com/time/photogallery/0,29307,1866765_1815174,00.html), [Work exhibited by M+B Gallery](http://www.mbart.com/artists/_Lisa%20Jack/_other%20works/_3244,14/), [Artist statement by Lisa Jack](http://www.mbart.com/artists/_Lisa%20Jack/_artist-statement/).

Comment: Those are great.

Comment: But why would you assume that a college nickname (should it exist) from 33 years ago would be indexed by Google?

Comment: You spend considerable part of your answer on "proof by Google", while in fact it neither proves nor disproves anything at all. Since it's not expected that the nickname from 33 years ago is indexed, date when it surfaced in digital era isn't really meaningful. The only thing that is know, is that FactBoook tweeted unsourced claim. Rest is just a speculation based on thesis that the claim is false.

Comment: "Factbook is the source of this information appearing online", not quite, Factbook is the source of this information appearing in indexable form. It might have been on-line for example as a video, but you won't find that with simple Google. And showing Google Trends is just a red herring.

Comment: Anyone who smoked weed in the days of their stupid youth (stupid because that is the general state of male youth, not because of MJ specifically), would eagerly court and lobby for a weed-related nickname, so I don't find that part especially doubtful..... or notable.